# Reinstall and use python3 outside of synced folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've put myself in a big ol' pickle. This morning, I unsynced some heavy folders from Box in order to save on power consumption and memory. What I didn't realize is that for some reason years ago I installed python within this synced drive that carries all my research. So a lot of dependencies broke after I unsynced a folder called `.local`. Since then I've re-synced the folder just to have it working for the day but it has 20,000 files in it and it's taking an eternity to patch things up. Little by little, I'm able to load more libraries, but it's just a bandaid and ultimately what I want to do is move all my python stuff from that synced drive to a local directory.

I'm using WSL. I've tried "uninstalling" and reinstalling `python3` using the Windows installer, but whenever I try to run a `.py` program from the terminal, I get the same errors as before, such as:

`cannot import name '_np_version_under1p14' from 'pandas.compat.numpy'`

and a little while later (after some files synced)

`AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'`

So it appears to still reference the same place that is currently missing some files due to the sync problem. That means it's still referencing the directory within the synced drive. How can I tell the terminal to use the packages installed elsewhere? I see a directory in `/mnt/usr/local/lib/python3.6/` that contains the `site-packages` I think I need. How can I use the terminal command `python3` to look for files in this other directory by default?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using the global python interpreter to run your scripts which is usually not the best thing to do.
You will run into dependency issues or things breaking like you described.

Much better way is to create a virtual environment, install all your dependencies like pandas, and run your scripts from there.

Create new virtual environment:

```
python -m venv .venv
```

Activate it:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Install dependencies:

```
pip install pandas
```

And then run your scripts.

If you have a lot dependencies you can use tools like python poetry to manage them. Also you'll get virtual environments helpers and locking for free.

https://python-poetry.org/

Comment: Do I have to do this every time I open the terminal? What if I have several dependencies that I need to install every time?